# How do I initialize PutItemInput struct using aws sdk go v2 to execute a PutItem on DynamoDb without this error?

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

When I try to initialize the input variable to do a PutItem on DynamoDB table using **aws go sdk v2**, it gives me an error - missing type in composite literal. I looked at the struct PutItemInput here - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb@v1.2.2#PutItemInput I don't understand how to get rid of this error? id is the partition key in mytable

```
input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
            TableName: aws.String("mytable"),
            Item: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
                "id": {
                    N: aws.String(a.ID),
                },
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
Item: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
    "id": &types.AttributeValueMemberN{a.ID},
}
```

[`types.AttributeValue`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb@v1.2.2/types#AttributeValue) is an interface type. When constructing maps or slices of interfaces you cannot elide the *concrete* type of the individual elements from the composite literal. You need to tell the compiler what *concrete* type you would like an element to have.

Comment: Compiler doesn't complain anymore with a little altered version of your code. input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String("mytable"),
    Item: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
     "id": &types.AttributeValueMemberN{string(a.ID)},
    },
   }

Comment: Depends on what the type of `a.ID` is which you have not specified, and since in your question you are using `aws.String(a.ID)` I assumed that `a.ID` is of type `string` since you can't pass anything else to [`aws.String`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2@v1.3.4/aws#String).

Answer (score 0):

### AWS SDK Go V2

type aStruct struct {
    `Id int64`
    `Name string`
}

var a = aStruct {
    `Id: 123`
    `Name: "DummyName"`
}

itemMap := map[string]types.AttributeValue{
    `"Id":  &types.AttributeValueMemberN{Value: strconv.Itoa(int(a.Id))},`
    `"Name":    &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: a.Name},`
}

itemInput := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    `Item:      itemMap,`
    `TableName: aws.String("mytable"),`
}

Answer (score -2):

The types.AttributeValue is an interface.It should be something as follows

```
input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("mytable"),
        Item: map[string]*types.AttributeValue{
            "id": {
                N: aws.String(a.ID),
            },
        },
    }
```